Serilog Not Working After New Azure Release: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.InOutOfProcHelper' threw an exception
I currently am working on a .NET 4.8 project deployed using an Azure pipeline. This project uses Serilog to write logs to a SQL database, and has been doing this for some time. The Serilog logic listed below:
            //Initialize Logger
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
              .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
                connectionString: ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SerilogConnection"].ConnectionString,
                sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
                {
                    TableName = "WEB_APIS_LOGS",
                    SchemaName = "dbo",
                    AutoCreateSqlTable = false
                },
                columnOptions: columnOpts
              )
              .CreateLogger();

How Serilog is being used:
 Log.Logger.Write(logEventLevel, "{Entity}{EntityId}{@ValidationResult}", "SalesOrder", order.OrderId, order.Rules);

Last week I made a small change that doesn't effect any logging logic whatsoever, and after I deployed it via our Azure pipeline the logging no longer works. I tried reverting to an earlier release and that did nothing. I thought it may be because I changed the pipeline name around this time, but still no luck after reverting it back.
I enabled self logging for Serilog locally to see what popped up, and I got the error "The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.InOutOfProcHelper' threw an exception.". I am not sure if this is just a local issue or not, but it is the only clue I possibly have to what is wrong. I am able to connect to the database just fine and have not touched any project packages so I do not know why there would suddenly be issues after this specific release. This is the newest release in over a year so maybe that has something to do with it, but again no substantial changes were made to the code and none were made to the pipeline so I am completely lost.
Configuration:
Web.config
     <system.web>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  </system.web>

Packages.config
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" version="5.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />


Please share your configuration file.

@SpicyPirate What changes have you made?

@SpicyPirate Check if the version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is compatible with your .NET version

@Harshitha I included some config in an edit but its not all showing here so here is relevant package.config info:       <package id="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" version="5.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />   <package id="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI" version="5.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />   <package id="Serilog" version="2.12.0" targetFramework="net48" />   <package id="Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />   <package id="Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net48" />

@Aslesha Kantamsetti
The only changes I made were some logic changes in the api, which boil down to adding some improved error handling and disabling certain steps. Nothing related to any Serilog or SQL functionality, and other than the Serilog issue the app works as expected.

I added a Serilog debugging log file to the server and got this error, so it turns out it is a certificate issue.
Unable to write 1 log events to the database due to following error: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
